# how to add constraint to make sure weights toward to 0 as much as possible in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, constraints, dropout

say we have a simple neural network with 4 `Dense` layers, Lin -> L1 -> L2 -> Lout; assume `L2 = matrix[1x5]` and the 5 values can be represented as `[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]`; when we train the model, we know there are lots of groups of `[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]` satisfying the data like `[1,2,3,4,5]` `[1,0,4,5,5]` `[0,0,15,0,0]` `[0,0,0,5,0]`;

**my question is how to add a constraint to the layer weights so that we can make sure most of them are 0**. for example, the 4 groups L2 weights `[1,2,3,4,5]` `[1,0,4,5,5]` `[0,0,15,0,0]` `[0,0,0,5,0]`, where the 3rd and 4th one has 4 zeros; and 5 < 15 so that we treat the 4th one as the most prior among the 4 groups.

we know TensorFlow Keras has the functionality: https://keras.io/api/layers/constraints/

but there are no built-in constraints for my question. any idea on how to write such a constraint or maybe there is another way to do this?

more specific, we have lots of vectors and we want to classify the vectors, we want a layer to recognize which columns are important (but we do not know exact columns, like word embedding, we need to transform a word to vector; here we need to transform a vector to importance bitmask and then do further processing) and we can drop out other columns. for example, we have features `[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]` and we got L2 `[0,0,0,5,0]`, then we can say, the 4th column is important so that we can transform the feature vector to `[0, 0, 0, 5 * x4, 0]`

thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so that we can make sure most of them are 0

if there is no **strict** requirements to the number of 0s (as you might have suggested in the single-column example) you are looking for [Lasso regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) (so called **L1** regularization) which, to simply put, penalizes the magnitude of each weight. The weight will only be big if it is absolutely crucial for the inference.

In tensorflow 2.x this can be done via [kernel regularizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/L1). Now, this enforces weights to be small, but it does not guarantee it will be 0. Furthermore, it strongly affects performance if used abusively.

As a side note, the problem you are **probably** trying to solve is related to machine learning interpretability/explainability, and while your approach is interesting, it might be worth looking at methods/models  constructed solely for this purpose (there are models that are able to produce feature significance etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use L1 and L2 loss.
A weights with L1 loss gets sparse. Many elements will be 0. A weights with L2 loss doesn't have many zeros, but L2 norm is small.